# Why did Lester follow Lorne Malvo?

Tags: fargo-tv

In the TV series *Fargo*, why did lester go behind Lorne Malvo when they meet after 1 year in the bar at Las Vegas even after Malvo threatens him to walk away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's just say Lester was under the influence of his newfound confidence which slightly tipped over into overconfidence when he followed Malvo. After last year's events, Lester thought of himself as a changed man, who would not be pushed over or chased away. Malvo initially just tried to ignore him and this offended Lester who then followed him to prove to himself that he can do whatever he wants.

Comment: This type of question is fairly subjective, but I tend to agree with @Ankit.  Lester is straight gangsta when he sends his new wife into the office to pick up the plane tickets.